# как правильно прописать команду в eslint

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

Как правильно прописать команду, что бы при ее выполнении eslint проходился по всем js файлам в проекте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй так. Должно работать eslint --fix 'src/**/*.js'